# How can I reset the position of my marker view when the cancel button is pressed?

Tags: swift

I have a ***markerView*** which you can grab and move around. I added a ***panGesture*** to it.

---

```
let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleDraggedView(_:)))
        fanMenu.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
```

---

To drag the view around and update the position of it:

```
    @objc func handleDraggedView(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
        if let marker = documentationMarkers.first(where: {$0.documentationId == documentationPressed.id}) {
            if(fanMenu.isOpen && marker.documentationType == "DEFAULT") {
                self.viewForTilingView.bringSubview(toFront: marker)

                let translation = sender.translation(in: self.viewForTilingView)
                marker.center = CGPoint(x: marker.center.x + translation.x, y: marker.center.y + translation.y)

                let point = viewForTilingView.convert(marker.center, to: scrollView)
                fanMenu.center = CGPoint(x: point.x,
                                         y: point.y)
                sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.viewForTilingView.superview)
                print("Startpoint-X: \(point.x)", "Startpoint-Y: \(point.y)")

                if(sender.state == .ended) {

                    print("Endpoint-X: \(point.x)", "Endpoint-Y: \(point.y)")

                    if let documentation = documentations.first(where: {$0.id == marker.documentationId}) {
                        let levelZoom : CGFloat = pow(2.0, CGFloat(viewForTilingView.tileProvider!.levelsOfDetail - 1))

                        let positionX = Int(marker.center.x * levelZoom)
                        let positionY = Int(marker.center.y * levelZoom)

                        _ = updatePosition(documentation: documentation, positionX: positionX, positionY: positionY)
                        documentationAdded(doc: documentation, update: true)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

- my start and endpoints are correct. When I long press my marker it prints the correct startpoints and when I release it somewhere else it gives me the correct endpoints.

I added some buttons to my marker view. Two of them are a ***cancel*** and ***confirm*** Button.
In a switch case statement it checks which button is selected. If the conform button is selected and you moved the marker around it updates the position ( = do nothing cause it updates it anyways) but when the cancel button is selected it should not update the postion and reset it to the old one.

```
func contextMenuButtonClicked(buttonId: String) {
        let doc = documentationPressed
        switch buttonId {
        case "main":
           break

        case "cancelButton":

        //update to the old position
```

My question is how can I get the old position of my marker view and place it to the start position when the user presses the cancel button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the marker position by switching between pan states.

For e.g.

```
//declare a variable inside your class- var olPostion = CGPoint()
if sender.state == .began { 
  oldPosition = marker.center
}
```

and on cancelButtonPress, reset the button position to old position

```
marker.center = oldPosition
```

> NOTE: If you want to reset the button position the position it was
>   when the view  controller loaded, assign the value od oldPosition in
>   viewDidLoad()